# Binding form with dynamic element names to a model class in MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, model

I was trying to bind the post-data of this form to a MVC model class,

```
<form>
  <div criteriaid=”59”>
    <input type="hidden" value="FRON 01" name="criteriaProduct[59]">
    <input type="hidden" value="FRON 02" name="criteriaProduct[59]">  
    <input type="hidden" value="FRON 04" name="criteriaProduct[59]">
  <div>

  <div criteriaid=”60”>
    <input type="hidden" value="FRON 02" name="criteriaProduct[60]">
    <input type="hidden" value="FRON 01" name="criteriaProduct[60]">  
    <input type="hidden" value="FRON 04" name="criteriaProduct[60]">
  <div>

  <div criteriaid=”61”>
    <input type="hidden" value="FRON 05" name="criteriaProduct[61]">
    <input type="hidden" value="FRON 06" name="criteriaProduct[61]">  
    <input type="hidden" value="FRON 01" name="criteriaProduct[61]">
  <div>
</form>
```

The problem is the criteria id is dynamic and the products has to be grouped by criteria Id.
I tried

```
Class
{
    public string[][] criteriaProduct { get; set; }  // not working
    public string[] criteriaProduct { get; set; } // not working
}
```

Any one can help? Thanks
I know this array name is ok in PHP, but c# ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Exactly full information about array binding is in [Hancelman blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)